# How can i remove the brackets from a list inside a dictionary that is imported from another file that is printed inside an fstring in Python?

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary

```
user_answer = input(f"{current_question.category}, {current_question.difficulty}\n{current_question.question_text}\nChoices: {current_question.question_answer}, {current_question.incorrect_answer}\n").lower()
```

This fstring prints:

```
Entertainment: Video Games, easy
League of Legends, DOTA 2, Smite and Heroes of the Storm are all part of which game genre?
Choices: Multiplayer Online Battle Arena (MOBA), ['Real Time Strategy (RTS)', 'First Person Shooter (FPS)', 'Role Playing Game (RPG)']
```

I'm trying to get the fstring to print the correct answer with the incorrect answers as a part of a multiple choice quiz, but the brackets are from the incorrect answers being inside a list.

Comment: Generate your own string from the list's contents instead of relying on `list.__str__` or `list.__repr__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to randomize the answers each time (otherwise the quiz might be a bit too easy?) you can try something like this:

```
import random

category = "Entertainment: Video Games"
difficulty = "easy"
question_text = "League of Legends, DOTA 2, Smite and Heroes of the Storm are all part of which game genre?"
question_answer = "Multiplayer Online Battle Arena (MOBA)"
incorrect_answer = ['Real Time Strategy (RTS)', 'First Person Shooter (FPS)', 'Role Playing Game (RPG)']

answers = incorrect_answer.copy() + [question_answer]
random.shuffle(answers)
answers_str = "\n".join(answers)
prompt = f"{category}, {difficulty}\n{question_text}\nChoices:\n {answers_str}\n"

user_answer = input(prompt).lower()
```

Output:

```
Entertainment: Video Games, easy
League of Legends, DOTA 2, Smite and Heroes of the Storm are all part of which game genre?
Choices: 
First Person Shooter (FPS)
Real Time Strategy (RTS)
Multiplayer Online Battle Arena (MOBA)
Role Playing Game (RPG)
```

Comment: Hey! This worked! And thank you for the randomization! I made a quiz consisting of 350 questions, (randomized as well of course) and I couldn't figure out how to include the answers for choices! I'm completely new to this, just now learning about classes, and that's what all that current_question.category came from! I input your code to experiment and didn't know i could do [question_answer] to append to the incorrect_answers! Also, who the heck down voted this :(

Answer (score 0):

Change `current_question.incorrect_answer` to `', '.join(current_question.incorrect_answer)` to convert it to a comma-delimited string.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_answer = input(f"{current_question.category}, {current_question.difficulty}\n{current_question.question_text}\nChoices: {current_question.question_answer}, {' '.join(current_question.incorrect_answer)}\n").lower()
```

I assume you just want to switch the lust into a string?